# How to obtain content_type from a Django Model Class?

Tags: python, django, django-models, content-management-system

I am trying to obtain the ContentType for a django models.Model.  Not trying to get the model from a ContentType, which is all I can find in the docs.  For example:

```
model_name = 'FooBar'
MyModel = apps.get_model('app_xyz', model_name)
MyModel
<class 'apps.app_xyz.models.FooBar'>
```

How do I get the ContentType of MyModel?  The only thing I can figure out to do is set the model_name string to lower and directly query ContentTypes:

```
ct = ContentType.objects.get(model=model_name.lower())
```

That seems really fragile, and using lower() has a code smell I don't like.  I've looked through FooBar's methods, _methods, and __methods to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
cc = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model)

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst what would you like me to explain in one line method call?

Comment: Any StackOverflow regulations notwithstanding, I thank you for giving me the solution!

Comment: @robline  Not at all.

Comment: @AlexeyPopov Hey hey. See Stackoverflow guideline. One-line answers risk to be deleted by the community, and if you want to avoid that, explain your answers.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst you have a point. However, retelling docs in my own words feels a bit odd to me. I provided a link to the relevant part of the official documentation and frankly I consider it to be enough. If guidelines dictate that this answer must be removed, so be it.

Anyway, I didn't mean to be hostile.